# oracle 10g express edition database connection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to add a from data to database 
and loaded class 12 drivers,tried ojdbc14 and ojdbc14_g too getting following errors

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;
    PrintWriter pwinsert = response.getWriter();
    String firstname=request.getParameter("fname");
    String Ddate=request.getParameter("ddate");
    String Email=request.getParameter("email");
    String ContactNo=request.getParameter("contactNo");
    String Address=request.getParameter("address");
    String complaint=request.getParameter("complaint");
    String dept=request.getParameter("dept");
      try {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          System.out.println("driver  loaded");
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)    {
          System.out.println("driver not loaded");

      }


      String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
      String Username = "system";
      String Password = "toushif";
    try
    {


         con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,Username,Password);
         ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TOU (MOBILE,DDATE,NAME,EMAIL,ADDRESS,COMPLAINT,DEPT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");
         ps.setString(1,ContactNo); 
         ps.setString(2,Ddate);
         ps.setString(3,firstname);
         ps.setString(4,Email);
         ps.setString(5,Address);
         ps.setString(6,complaint);
         ps.setString(7,dept);

         int i = ps.executeUpdate();
         pwinsert.println(i);

         if(i!=0)    {
             pwinsert.println("data has been stored");
         }
         else    {
             pwinsert.println("data could not be stored");
         }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

getting this error
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

```
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at tou.nadaf.database.doPost(database.java:74)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Probably not related by `ojdbc14.jar` and especially `classes12.jar` are **totally** outdated and obsolete. Please use a more recent driver (e.g. `ojdbc6.jar`). The number in the driver's file name indicates the **Java** version it should be running on - it's not the driver's version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

not

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

assuming you have the right `jar` on the classpath.

`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` was replaced by `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` in `10g`.